# Debugger detaching when connecting to a Blackberry Device

Tags: blackberry

I tested my application on the emulator and it was working fine. The flow of the application is Splash Screen >> Login Screen >>..... . I uploaded the application on the device after signing it. When the application starts in debug mode the Splash screen appears and moves on to the Login screen but as soon as the login screen appears the debugger detaches. My device do not have a sim card and i am working with a wi-fi connection. Is it required to have a sim card inserted in the device? and also is it required to have the BB Services activated??

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not all devices are working in debug mode, e.g. os7 devices definitely not; anyway, it's unrelated to sim/bis and has to do with rim's development tools being beta quality